Add configuration information block to json file with powershell scripts
I have a Json file as configuration file, like below:
{
    "managedApiConnections": {
        "Testoffice365_Connection_1": {
            "api": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/.../office365"
            },
            "authentication": {
                "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
            },
            "connection": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/.../Test_Connection_1"
            },
            "connectionRuntimeUrl": "https://.../office365/xxx3501"
        },
        "Testsql_Connection_1": {
            "api": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastasia/managedApis/sql"
            },
            "authentication": {
                "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
            },
            "connection": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql_SIT"
            },
            "connectionProperties": {
                "authentication": {
                    "audience": "https://database.windows.net/",
                    "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
                }
            },
            "connectionRuntimeUrl": "https://8xxxx.02.common.logic-eastasia.azure-apihub.net/apim/sql/xxxx1b"
        }
    },
    "serviceProviderConnections": {
        "Testblob_Connection_1": {
            "displayName": "blobxxx",
            "parameterSetName": "ManagedServiceIdentity",
            "parameterValues": {
                "authProvider": {
                    "Type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
                },
                "blobStorageEndpoint": "@appsetting('blob_url_test')"
            },
            "serviceProvider": {
                "id": "/serviceProviders/AzureBlob"
            }
        },
        "Testsql_Connection_2": {
            "displayName": "SQL_xxxx",
            "parameterSetName": "ManagedServiceIdentity",
            "parameterValues": {
                "authProvider": {
                    "Type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
                },
                "databaseName": "xxxx ",
                "managedIdentityType": "SystemAssigned",
                "serverName": "xxxx.database.windows.net"
            },
            "serviceProvider": {
                "id": "/serviceProviders/sql"
            }
        }
    }
}

Now, since the needs of automation, in order to meet the new connection instances, I need to add additional configuration information to this configuration file, like add a new O365 connection, that I need add using powershell to get the content from below json template then add it Before the node Testoffice365_Connection_1：
{
    "<APIConnectionName>_<DeployENV>": {
    "api": {
        "id": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionsID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastasia/managedApis/office365"
    },
    "authentication": {
        "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
    },
    "connection": {
        "id": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionsID>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroups>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/<APIConnectionName>_<DeployENV>"
    },
    "connectionRuntimeUrl": "https://xxxx/office365/<connectionRuntimeUrl>"
    }
}

Note: When add the template to the Json file, the outermost braces are not needed.
How to using powershell scripts to achieve it?

EDIT: simplified version, as I realized an array is fine, too.
$BaseObj = $BaseJson | ConvertFrom-Json
$TemplateObj = $TemplateJson | ConvertFrom-Json

$BaseObj.managedApiConnections = $TemplateObj, $BaseObj.managedApiConnections | ForEach-Object { $_ }

$BaseObj | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

ORIGINAL:
Here: please note I did insert the contents of the template literally.
# if the JSON are hardcoded in the script
# just use only ConvertFrom-Json, if they aren't already converted somewhere else in the script
$BaseJson = Get-Content $BaseJsonFilePath
$TemplateJson = Get-Content $TemplateJsonFilePath

$BaseObj = $BaseJson | ConvertFrom-Json
$TemplateObj = $TemplateJson | ConvertFrom-Json

$NewManagedApiCollectionObj = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()

$TemplateObj, $BaseObj.managedApiConnections | ForEach-Object { $NewManagedApiCollectionObj.Add($_) }

$BaseObj.managedApiConnections = $NewManagedApiCollectionObj

$BaseObj | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100


to be efficient, maybe just $BaseJson = Get-Content $JsonFile where $JsonFile = 'path of json file'

@Mr.Key7  This is just a snippet for the important parts, I'm expecting the actual JSON files\contents being managed\manipulated elsewhere in his script.

Good job. Just give an alternative way for asker.

@Mr.Key7 mighty right, in fact I edited the answer to make it a bit more generic(and much shorter)

Thanks for your reply, it works for me. Sorry for the late confirmation, because it is a problem I researched in my spare time, so I only have time to verify it today.

no problem, I even just realized An Array Is Fine, Too and update the solution
